# How to get data from JSON having 2 dimensional array in android

Tags: java, android, json, multidimensional-array

In my android app, I have this JSON which looks like this :

```
{ "first_name": "ankit",
  "last_name": "anurag",
  "mobile": "8105580517",
  "interest_input": [13, 14],
  "user_cards": [
       [17, "DBS NUS Alumni Platinum Card "],
       [19, "DBS NUS Debit Card "]
       ],
  "email": "ankit_anurag@stragure.com"}
```

As you can see for the "user_cards" key the value is a 2 dimensional Array, with id & name.
I want to get these both.

The code I have written for this is here :

JSONArray existingCards = o.getJSONArray("user_cards");

```
                exCards = new String[existingCards.length()][2];//populate ur Array with blanks to avoid entrance of null values


                //fill up the blanks to prevent null
                for(int i = 0; i < existingCards.length(); i++){

                     exCards[i][0] = "";
                     exCards[i][1] = "";


                    }

                //fill up the actual data
                for(int i = 0; i < existingCards.length(); i++){

                    String k = exCards[i][0];
                    String l = exCards[i][1];
                    Log.v("exC", k+" "+l);

                    }
```

But I am not able to retrieve the data. Please Help

Comment: You first assign empty strings to each array item and then read them!? Of course they will be empty.

Comment: I am very sorry. I put up the wrong code actually. This is stupid of course and very embarrassing. I m sorry

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize each of the "row" arrays first:

```
exCards[0] = new String[SIZE];
exCards[1] = new String[SIZE];
```

Yo can do it in the foor-loop